plus-amending .[;;+;] nested dictionaries - limit order book example
Capturing orders in the multi-exchange order book can be structured like so:
q)init:{B::(1#`)!enlist x!count[x]#enlist `s#(enlist 0Np)!enlist (0#0Ni)!(0#0Ni)} / [e(x)changes]:initialized global order (B)ook
q)add0:{.[`B;-1 _ x;:;last x]}     / [orders:(`sym;`ex;tstam(p);px(i);sz(i))]:(add)ed to (B)ook
q)add:{ .[`B;-1 _ x;+;last x]}     / [orders:(`sym;`ex;tstam(p);px(i);sz(i))]:(add)ed to (B)ook
q)state::(+/'')B    / state view of the order book, rolling up all the events; `state is a view as per https://code.kx.com/q/learn/views/

We can add orders individually:
q)ti:2024.05.07D14                / timestamp
q)init `binance`bybit             / initialize order book B
q)B[`btc;`binance;ti;62i]:5i      / order to buy 5 BTC on Binance for 62 gets added as bid (no matching here)
q)B[`eth;`binance;ti;3000i]:6i
q)B[`btc;`bybit;ti;62i]:-2i       / sell order gets added as ask (no matching)
q)B[`eth;`bybit;ti;3000i]:1i
q)B
   | binance                                                              bybit                                                               
   | -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | `s#(`s#,0Np)!,(`int$())!`int$()                                      `s#(`s#,0Np)!,(`int$())!`int$()                                     
btc| `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,62i)!,5i)   `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,62i)!,-2i) 
eth| `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,3000i)!,6i) `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,3000i)!,1i)
q)state
   | binance           bybit            
   | -----------------------------------
   | (`int$())!`int$() (`int$())!`int$()
btc| (,62i)!,5i        (,62i)!,-2i      
eth| (,3000i)!,6i      (,3000i)!,1i     

We can amend vectors of orders in bulk like so: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/amend/#cross-sections
q)ti:2024.05.07D15
q)add0 (`btc;`binance;ti; 62 65i;   4 -1i);
q)state
   | binance           bybit            
   | -----------------------------------
   | (`int$())!`int$() (`int$())!`int$()
btc| 62 65i!9 -1i      (,62i)!,-2i      
eth| (,3000i)!,6i      (,3000i)!,1i     
q)B
   | binance                                                                                                       bybit                                                               
   | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | `s#(`s#,0Np)!,(`int$())!`int$()                                                                               `s#(`s#,0Np)!,(`int$())!`int$()                                     
btc| `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000 2024.05.07D15:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,62i)!,5i;62 65i!4 -1i) `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,62i)!,-2i) 
eth| `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,3000i)!,6i)                                          `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,3000i)!,1i)

However, if two orders arrive at identical time and price, only the last in the sequence gets captured with this .[;;:;] assign form, previous values overwritten:
q)ti:2024.05.07D16
q)add0 (`btc;`binance;ti; 62 62i; 10 20i);
q)B
   | binance                                                                                                                                                 bybit                                                               
   | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | `s#(`s#,0Np)!,(`int$())!`int$()                                                                                                                         `s#(`s#,0Np)!,(`int$())!`int$()                                     
btc| `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000 2024.05.07D15:00:00.000000000 2024.05.07D16:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,62i)!,5i;62 65i!4 -1i;(,62i)!,20i) `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,62i)!,-2i) 
eth| `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,3000i)!,6i)                                                                                    `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,3000i)!,1i)
q)state
   | binance           bybit            
   | -----------------------------------
   | (`int$())!`int$() (`int$())!`int$()
btc| 62 65i!29 -1i     (,62i)!,-2i      
eth| (,3000i)!,6i      (,3000i)!,1i     

Inspired by this semantic:
q)(1 2!3 4)+2 5!-6 -7
1| 3
2| -2
5| -7

we introduce .[;;+;] in place of .[;;:;] :
q)add (`btc;`binance;ti; 62 62i; 10 20i);
q)B
   | binance                                                                                                                                                 bybit                                                               
   | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | `s#(`s#,0Np)!,(`int$())!`int$()                                                                                                                         `s#(`s#,0Np)!,(`int$())!`int$()                                     
btc| `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000 2024.05.07D15:00:00.000000000 2024.05.07D16:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,62i)!,5i;62 65i!4 -1i;(,62i)!,50i) `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,62i)!,-2i) 
eth| `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,3000i)!,6i)                                                                                    `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,3000i)!,1i)
q)state
   | binance           bybit            
   | -----------------------------------
   | (`int$())!`int$() (`int$())!`int$()
btc| 62 65i!59 -1i     (,62i)!,-2i      
eth| (,3000i)!,6i      (,3000i)!,1i     

The problem is that it only works with the pre-existing keys, not when new keys would have to be created with this amend:
q)add (`btc;`binance;2024.05.07D15; 63 64i; 100 -300i);
q)B
   | binance                                                                                                                                                                bybit                                                               
   | -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | `s#(`s#,0Np)!,(`int$())!`int$()                                                                                                                                        `s#(`s#,0Np)!,(`int$())!`int$()                                     
btc| `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000 2024.05.07D15:00:00.000000000 2024.05.07D16:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,62i)!,5i;62 65 63 64i!4 -1 100 -300i;(,62i)!,50i) `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,62i)!,-2i) 
eth| `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,3000i)!,6i)                                                                                                   `s#0N 2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000!((`int$())!`int$();(,3000i)!,1i)
q)state
   | binance                      bybit            
   | ----------------------------------------------
   | (`int$())!`int$()            (`int$())!`int$()
btc| 62 65 63 64i!59 -1 100 -300i (,62i)!,-2i      
eth| (,3000i)!,6i                 (,3000i)!,1i     

q)ti:2024.05.07D17
q)add (`btc;`binance;ti; 63 64i; 100 -300i);
'length
  [1]  add:{ .[`B;-1 _ x;+;last x]}
             ^
q))

Is there an elegant solution to maintaining order book where two orders can have identical timestamp and where it's ok to capture those two orders as sum of sizes at that level?

Edit:
Indexing one level higher does not work either, e.g. in clean environment without pre-existing keys:
q)init:{B::(1#`)!enlist x!count[x]#enlist `s#(enlist 0Np)!enlist (0#0Ni)!(0#0Ni)}
q)add2:{.[`B;-2 _ x;+;last[-1_x]!last x]}
q)init `binance`bybit
q)add2 (`btc;`binance;2024.05.07D15; 62 65i; 4 -1i);
'length
  [1]  add2:{.[`B;-2 _ x;+;last[-1_x]!last x]}
             ^
q))



well explained! What if you were more explicit about the dictionary structure (and indexing one level higher) within the add function? e.g.
q)add2:{.[`B;-2 _ x;+;last[-1_x]!last x]}

Then I think it works
q)ti:2024.05.07D17
q)add2 (`btc;`binance;ti; 63 64i; 100 -300i);
q)
q)B[`btc;`binance]
                             | (`int$())!`int$()
2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000| (,62i)!,5i
2024.05.07D15:00:00.000000000| 62 65 63 64i!4 -1 100 -300i
2024.05.07D16:00:00.000000000| 62 62i!40 20i
2024.05.07D17:00:00.000000000| 63 64i!100 -300i

and I think it also solves your issue of duplicates
q)ti:2024.05.07D16
q)add2 (`btc;`binance;ti; 62 62i; 10 20i);
q)
q)B[`btc;`binance]
                             | (`int$())!`int$()
2024.05.07D14:00:00.000000000| (,62i)!,5i
2024.05.07D15:00:00.000000000| 62 65i!4 -1i
2024.05.07D16:00:00.000000000| 62 62i!10 20i

But in this case (if you allow the duplicate 62 as above) then your state view won't sum the two 62's in the same dictionary. So you might need to revisit that - possibly by aggregating the last[-1_x]!last x dictionary prior to appending it
EDIT: failing the above, you could also implement a try-both approach which would work but may have a slight performance hit. I don't think you're going to find one in-place amend that's going to do everything you're trying to do.
q)add0:{.[B;-1 _ x;:;last x]}
q)add:{ .[B;-1 _ x;+;last x]}
q)tryAdd:{`B set @[add;x;{y;add0 x}x]}
q)init `binance`bybit
q)
q)tryAdd (`btc;`binance;2024.05.07D15; 62 65i; 4 -1i);
q)B[`btc;`binance]
                             | (`int$())!`int$()
2024.05.07D15:00:00.000000000| 62 65i!4 -1i
q)ti:2024.05.07D16
q)tryAdd (`btc;`binance;ti; 62 62i; 10 20i);
q)tryAdd (`btc;`binance;ti; 62 62i; 10 20i);
q)B[`btc;`binance]
                             | (`int$())!`int$()
2024.05.07D15:00:00.000000000| 62 65i!8 -2i
2024.05.07D16:00:00.000000000| (,62i)!,50i
q)ti:2024.05.07D17
q)tryAdd (`btc;`binance;ti; 63 64i; 100 -300i);
q)B[`btc;`binance]
                             | (`int$())!`int$()
2024.05.07D15:00:00.000000000| 62 65i!8 -2i
2024.05.07D16:00:00.000000000| (,62i)!,50i
2024.05.07D17:00:00.000000000| 63 64i!100 -300i


add2 reproduced with 'length error in a clean environment; edited the question to show that attempt

Edited answer with alternative try-both approach. Should work for both your original add functions or the one-level-higher add function(s)
